# error could not find or load the main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMastererror

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a spark cluster for my Python ML code but I keep getting this

```
application failed:  Application failed 2 times due to AM Container: exited with exitCode: 1 , with it could not find or load the main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMastererror.
```

I have Hadoop version 3.3.6 and spark 3.4.1. Here are the logs files:

```
Application application_1694175708892_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1694175708892_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-09-08 15:36:40.531]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
"Setting up env variables"
"Setting up job resources"
"Copying debugging information"
C:\tmp\hadoop-UCKAN\nm-local-dir\usercache\UCKAN\appcache\application_1694175708892_0001\container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001>rem Creating copy of launch script
C:\tmp\hadoop-UCKAN\nm-local-dir\usercache\UCKAN\appcache\application_1694175708892_0001\container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001>copy "launch_container.cmd" "C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.3.6/logs/userlogs/application_1694175708892_0001/container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001/launch_container.cmd"
1 file(s) copied.
C:\tmp\hadoop-UCKAN\nm-local-dir\usercache\UCKAN\appcache\application_1694175708892_0001\container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001>rem Determining directory contents
C:\tmp\hadoop-UCKAN\nm-local-dir\usercache\UCKAN\appcache\application_1694175708892_0001\container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001>dir 1>>"C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.3.6/logs/userlogs/application_1694175708892_0001/container_1694175708892_0001_02_000001/directory.info"
"Launching container"
[2023-09-08 15:36:40.534]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
[2023-09-08 15:36:40.534]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-X:8088/cluster/app/application_1694175708892_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

This is my spark submit command:

```
spark-submit
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--num-executors 1 
--executor-cores 3 
--executor-memory 6g 
"C:\Users\UCKAN\Desktop\Python_Codes\Demo-Churn\BigDataML.py"
```

This the spark session:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("yarn") \
   .appName("churn_modellemesi") \
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "6g") \
   .config("spark.executor.instances", "1") \
   .config("spark.executor.cores", "2") \
   .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
   .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g") \
   .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true") \
   .getOrCreate()
```

I have tried/verified the following:

1. environment variables: HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR have been set in my Environment Variables to their correct paths
2. HADOOP_CONF_DIR have been defined in spark-env.cmd

any help would be appreciated thx.
ps. I didnt have any problems when I was submitting apps in standalone mode so I think the problem might be in YARN or Hadoop

I was trying to submit a Python app to a Spark cluster with YARN so that I could use both worker's and master's pcs CPUs to make my model run faster

Comment: Please add your error as text. For more information why, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: please show how you define your sparkSession

Comment: @Tal  I have included the spark session as you requested

Comment: can you try instead of master("yarn") use master("local[*]")

Comment: @tal but if I do that I wont be able to use both PC's CPUs simultaneously.